# How can I teleport someone to spawn based on team and position?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make it so that a specific player who enters a region, anywhere between 730, 0, 110 and 760, 256, 137, gets teleported to spawn. I managed to make it so whenever *anyone* entered the area it would teleport the target player to spawn, but my main goal is to make it so that I can walk around freely while my friend is locked out without having him teleported to spawn 10 times every second. I tried using teams but that wouldn't work either, but maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

I've been using this command, `goawayree` being the team I created with the target in it.

```
execute if entity @a[team=goawayree][x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50] run tp @a[team=goawayree] 0 72 0
```

this was using radius' as i couldnt figure out how i would make a set boundary without 300 armor stands and 13 different headaches.
if this isnt possible please please please point out a  similar way to do this, ive been looking for solutions online for about 3 days.
thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3):

With selectors, all filters(or the values in the square brackets) go in one array(square brackets).  It would be in the form of `name=value,name=value,name=value` and it keeps going until you don't have any other filters to add.  So you need to combine `team=goawayree` with `x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50` in one array to make `[team=goawayree, x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50]`.  You also are teleporting everyone on the `goawayree` team, when any player is in the rectangular prism `x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50`.  You can fix this by using just a `tp` command, selecting everyone on `goawayree` team in the rectangular prism, and tping them to spawn.  Here is how you do that.

```
tp @a[team=goawayree, x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50] 0 72 0
```

That command in theory should work.  If you have any problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two brackets and insert a comma `,`:

```
@a[team=goawayree][x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50]
                 ↑↑
```

to end up with this:

```
@a[team=goawayree,x=730,y=0,z=110,dx=50,dy=256,dz=50]
```

Also note an interesting quirk about `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`. The axes of the box you create are actually one more than what you type in. So actually, `0` is a one-block wide box.

If you want a 50×50 box, you should put 49 instead.